# Facebook Graph API to get public post of the public page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I want to access the `public post of the public page` in `php script`. Is there any feasibility to get this data from facebook pages. I have checked the documentation and found out as below url.

`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens`

Here it is providing the access to the pages which are created by me but not for the other user pages. So how can i get access to other user's pages post.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 12):

You have to apply for "Page Public Content Access": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

After approval, you can just use the same API call as for your own pages (/page-id/feed) with any Access Token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/page/feed

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you said. i didn't understand.

Comment: i have added another link about the api call. it includes example code too.

Comment: actually we required page feed but it is possible to get public pages data from my access token? Or we need to allow page to login and give permission to app to get the public data of that page?

Comment: you can either get data for pages you manage, with a page token of that page, OR you need to apply for page public content access, as you can read in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have read manage permission document carefully user given you access for the pages
`Manage Pages` and `publish Pages` on login after you access the post.
[Developer manage pages permissin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login-permissions/#manage-pages)